# Does $\operatorname{D}(X)\cong \operatorname{D}(Y)$ imply $X\cong Y$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be smooth projective varieties and by $\operatorname{D}(X)$ we mean the derived category of the category of bounded complexes of coherent sheaves on $X$. It is well-known that there might exist an equivalence $\operatorname{D}(X)\simeq \operatorname{D}(Y)$ even if $X\not \cong Y$. What if there is an isomorphism $\operatorname{D}(X) \cong \operatorname{D}(Y)$? Does it necessarily imply that $X\cong Y$?

Comment: The derived category is only well-defined up to equivalence anyway; it's very unnatural to ask questions about categories up to isomorphism.

Comment: it's very unnatural to talk about isomorphisms of categories even when they are not derived

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By a theorem of Bondal and Orlov (http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9712029) the answer is yes for varieties with ample canonical or anticanonical bundle.

Comment: Am I misreading the intro to this paper? It seems to me that the paper only deals with equivalence of (graded) derived categories, not isomorphism. (Which is what I would have expected anyway...)

Comment: isn't an isomorphism in particular an equivalence?

Comment: Yes, but not the other way around. I don't see any isomorphisms of categories in this paper. I guess what this is really saying is that when the canonical or anticanonical bundle is ample, the original condition (equivalence of derived categories) determines $X$ up to isomorphism. The extra (and unnatural) notion of "isomorphism" of derived categories is still superfluous.